# How to xfail off a conditional involving a parametrization?

Tags: pytest

## How to xfail off a conditional involving a parametrization?

The issue is that `@pytest.mark.xfail(condition=(code == 123), reason="123 is an exception case")` doesn't work because code is a parametrized variable. I tried some different things including static class members, globals, and setting it in the `expected_setup` fixture. None of these worked (as expected)

```
@pytest.mark.xfail(condition=(code == 123), reason="123 is an exception case")
E   NameError: name 'code' is not defined
```

```
params = [
    cls1,
    cls2,
    cls3,
    cls4
]
@pytest.mark.parametrize('code', params, ids=list(map(str, params)))
class TestContextExit(object):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def expected_setup(self, code):
        self.str1 = 'JETFUEL'
        self.str2 = 'OPERATIONNORTHWOODS'
        self.setup = NewStore(self.str1, self.str2, code)

    def test1(self, code):
        assert self.root.results.result_code == expected_result_code
        assert self.root.results.ta['result_code'] == expected_result_code.code
        assert self.root.results.result_code == expected_result_code

    @pytest.mark.xfail(condition=(code == 123), reason="123 is an exception case")
    def test2(self, code):
        assert self.setup.root['code'] == code

    @pytest.mark.xfail(condition=(code == 123), reason="123 is an exception case")
    def test3(self, code):
        assert self.setup.root['setup'] == NOERROR
```

Any ideas or patterns? Looking at the xfail pytest docs, I don't see any examples xfailing off parametrizations, except for the as part of the params. But in this case, the class is being parametrized and only two of the class tests turn into xfails, not all the tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pytest.param with xfail mark as a param value in parametrization to xfail a param.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(code, [1,pytest.param(0,marks=pytest.mark.xfail(reason="reasons")]
def test_a():
    assert code
```

This is used to mark certain parametrization value. This will xfail 2nd test.